# How to import Choices.js into webpack 4?

Tags: webpack

I am trying to import the module Choices.js into webpack.

1. My entry file (app.js): 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrXxD.png)
2. My package.json
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bw6N.png)
   The Code is compiled in the bundle but I cant create a new instance of Choices.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

change

import Choices from "choices.js";

to

import * from "choices.js";